# Accessing properties in nested function returning another function

Tags: javascript, function, nested, return, return-value

Is there a way to access properties in nested functions like that :

```
function func(){

  this.new_func=function(){
  console.log("something");
  return 'something';
  }

 this.someValue=7;

 return  function(){
 return "something_diff";
  };
}

var obj=new func();

obj(); //works with returning "something diff"
obj.new_func(); // TypeError: obj.new_func is not a function
obj.someValue; // undefined
```

I need to delete whole "return function()..." part in order to access "someValue" and "new_func()". **Why is it acting like that, and is there a way to somehow access that properties, while still returning another function ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a constructor that returns an object, that object replaces whatever you assigned to `this`. So indeed, the members `new_func` and `someValue` are lost.

To combine the returned function together with the other members, you can do this:

```js
function func() {
    var f = function() {
        return "something_diff";
    };
    f.new_func = function() {
        console.log("something"); 
        return 'something';
    }
    f.someValue = 7;
    return f;
}

var obj = new func();

console.log(obj());
obj.new_func();
console.log('someValue:', obj.someValue);
```

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var parentFunction =  function() {

    var nestedFunction = function() {
        var value = "nestedValue";
        var moreValues = "more values";
        return {
            value: value,
            moreValues: moreValues
        }
    }
    var anotherNestedFunction = function() {
        var anotherValue = "nestedValue";
        return anotherValue;
    }
    return {
        nested: nestedFunction,
        another: anotherNestedFunction
    }
}
```

Then:

```
    var newFunction = new parentFunction();
var nested = newFunction.nested();
console.log("nested value: ", nested.value);
console.log("another nested value: ", newFunction.another);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mn2gt2h6/) is a working example:

Comment: The idea here is that the function needs to return something, if you want to have access to the functions internals you will need to return an object with the variables you want to expose on it as properties. Otherwise you could just return a primitive of some sort (String, Integer, etc.). you could also assign all the variables like "this.variable =  'something'" and then the function would return "this". which is the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it acting like that, and is there a way to somehow access that properties, while still returning another function ??

Because of the pharenteis:

```
var obj=new func();
```

Basically you're firing your function and what is stored the variable obj is what the "func" **returns**.

In order to access to private properties, you should look at the Closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Yes, but without returning function, I can access those properties with the same way of creating that object.

Comment: That's why you're creating an instance of object. If you explicitly return a value from you function, that will be the only thing stored in variable (and it could be also another getter function which can access to the properties situated in the "closure scope".